# How to use expectationForNotification

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xctestexpectation

I've tried everything, but the only way I could get a successful test is to actually send the notification in the test function, which kinda defeats the purpose.

I have a button.  When I tap the button, it sends a notification.  How can I use expectationForNotification to see if this notification gets sent?

```
func testExample() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let button = app.buttons["Button"]
    let expectation = expectationForNotification("TEST_NOTE", object: nil) {
        (notification: NSNotification!) -> Bool in

        print("SUCCESS")
        return true
    }

    button.tap()

    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(5, handler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it looks to me that you will have to fulfill the expectation...

```
func testExample() 
{
     let app = XCUIApplication()
     let button = app.buttons["Button"]

     let expectation = expectationWithDescription("waiting for the tap")

      expectationForNotification("TEST_NOTE", object: nil)
      {
        notification in
        expectation.fulfill()
        return true
      }

      button.tap()

      waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(30)
      {
            error in 
            if let e = error
            {
                XCTFail("\(e.debugDescription)")
            }
       } 
}
```